# Connecting to external mysql db via kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am deploying the spring cloud dataflow kubernetes server. this deployment also deploys a mysql server in the cluster but i would like to write a service to connect to my mysql server which is on amazon aws instead of deploying one on kubernetes. Can i do this using external name type or something? Also, how can i give the username and password to connect to this db?

Comment: In gcloud you can https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine, so I guess u can do it in Amazon WS

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default [`mysql`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/tree/master/src/kubernetes/mysql) specific deployment configurations. More details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_deploy_services_and_dataflow) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms).

Once you have the above-taken care, you'd update Spring Datasource configuration defined in [SCDF deployment](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/blob/master/src/kubernetes/server/server-config-rabbit.yaml#L27), so you can point to the external cluster.

We will further clarify this in the reference guide.